# Entity relationship in Apigee

Tags: entity-relationship, apigee

I am new to Apigee, and confused with how entity relationships work. I have one collection called `artists` with the following entity:

```
{
  "artist": "",
  "profileImage": "",
  "genre": "",
  "style": ""
}
```

And another called `releases` like so:

```
{
    "release":"",
    "artist_uuid":""
    "label": "",

    "format":"",
        "tracks":[
            {"title":""}
            {"title":""}
            {"title":""}
            {"title":""}            
        ]
}
```

I want to know how to link the two so when I select `artist` it can give all the releases to that `artist`?  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You bet. You can join these together using connections. Use POST to connect the two entities like this:

POST https://api.usergrid.com/my-org/my-app/artists/UUID/releases/releases/UUID

Then, you can access the releases of the artists like so:

GET https://api.usergrid.com/my-org/my-app/artists/UUID/releases

(Also note: You won't need the artist_uuid field in your release entity.)

You can find more information here:

http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/entity-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You could do it one of 2 ways. One way is that you could embed your 'releases' collection inside of your 'artists' collection so that you don't have a need to 'join'. Alternatively, you could keep the 2 collections that you have and query the releases collection (programmatically) when you have the artist identified. But you can't use like a relational database and join them automatically at query time.